# Elasticsearch geo point union or similar

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Does anyone know what the simplest way of achieving a union in Elasticsearch?

I have many documents with a field `disease_name` and a `lat/lon` field.

e.g.

```
{
  "disease_name": 'Flu',
  "location": {
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
  }
}
```

I want to find all diseases that occur within all geo polygons.
(An OR query is not a suitable option as this may find any diseases that exist in just one area).

This is easy enough as a 'find one or more' because then it is just an OR query with multiple polygons and running the Elasticsearch terms aggregate.

**EDIT** - Additional Information about the use case

I wish to perform a UNION and INTERSECT.
Programmatically, forgetting ES for a moment, the way I would achieve this is as follows:

1. Assume I have a large array of documents

   ```
   [
     {
       "disease_name": 'Flu',
       "location": {
         "lat": 41.12,
         "lon": -71.34
       }
     },
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. Assume I have multiple geo buckets(geo polygons) defined.
3. For each disease, does it exist in all buckets, if not then throw away the document.
4. List all distinct disease_name values for the documents that remain.

I wish to avoid doing this programmatically if at all possible.

Comment: can you share an example result you are looking to produce? not clear what you are seeking to achieve here.

Comment: Added more detail to question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have correct mapping (as geopoint for location),

I think this might help.

```
POST x/diseases/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "geo_polygon": {
                        "location": {
                           "points": [
                              {
                                 "lat": 40.73,
                                 "lon": -74.1
                              },
                              {
                                 "lat": 40.83,
                                 "lon": -75.1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "geo_polygon": {
                        "location": {
                           "points": [
                              {
                                 "lat": 40.73,
                                 "lon": -74.1
                              },
                              {
                                 "lat": 40.83,
                                 "lon": -75.1
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "diseases": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "disease_name"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here, you can change the coordinates and if you want add similar filter for other polygons.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. I have already mentioned an OR query in my question. The use case is to find all areas that have a disease in common. Your answer above will find diseases that exist in at least one area, in addition to all of them.

Comment: Added more detail to question.

Comment: Replaced filter with and, does this help ??